# Modal not displayed in Vuejs

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I am using [this](https://github.com/euvl/vue-js-modal) library to create a modal component to display info. In my modal component the data is passed through parent which sets the variable to show the modal or not. But I am not able to display the modal.
Please look into my code and let me know if I am going wrong somewhere.

**Code for the modal component**

```
<template>
 <div>

   <div v-if="showmodal">

    <modal name="hello-world">
    <p>{{ modalDetails.final.price }} </p>
    <p> {{ modalDetails.final.productname}} </p>
    </modal>

  </div>
 </div>


</template>

<script>
import axios from 'axios'


export default{
name : 'ModalDisplay',
props : ['skuDetails'],

data(){
    return {
        modalDetails : {},
        showmodal : false
    }
},

watch:{
    sku: function(){
        this.getskudetails()
    }
},
computed :{
    sku : function(){
        return this.skuDetails
    }
},
methods:{
    getskudetails(){

        let url = "http://localhost:5000/details/"+ this.sku
        console.log(url)
        axios.get(encodeURI(url)).then((resp)=>{
            this.modalDetails ={ "final":resp.data.response.Results.Results[0] }


        }).catch(err => {
            console.log("we got an error the url is " + url)
            console.log(err);
        })

        this.showmodal = true    
    },

show () {
this.$modal.show('hello-world');
},
hide () {
this.$modal.hide('hello-world');
   }
  }
 }
</script>

<style>
</style>
```

**I have imported vue-js-modal in main.js**

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App'

import VModal from 'vue-js-modal'

Vue.use(VModal)

Vue.config.productionTip = false


export const EventBus = new Vue();

/* eslint-disable no-new */
new Vue({
   el: '#app',
   components: { App },
   template: '<App/>'
 })
```

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that `show()` and `hide()` never been called from your code. And from the document provided by **vue-js-modal**. I noticed that their demo use `show()` method rather than `v-if` directive to show modal. Please try remove `v-if` and replace setting value of **showmodal** with call method `show()` and `hide()`, just like following code snippet.

```
getskudetails(){
    let url = "http://localhost:5000/details/"+ this.sku
    console.log(url)
    axios.get(encodeURI(url)).then((resp)=>{
        this.modalDetails ={ "final":resp.data.response.Results.Results[0] }
        this.show();

    }).catch(err => {
        console.log("we got an error the url is " + url)
        console.log(err);
    })
```

template:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <h1>test</h1>
      <modal name="hello-world">
        <p>{{ modalDetails.final.price }} </p>
        <p> {{ modalDetails.final.productname}} </p>
      </modal>
  </div>
</template>
```

BTW, I think it's better timing to show modal when sku details request is  completed because these data will be used for rendering. So in the code snippet I pasted, I moved show modal code to axios resolved callback.

Comment: I tried the changes you suggested. But unfortunately it  didn't work.

Comment: have you remove the `v-if` directive from **template**?

Comment: yes kevin I did that.
But even then it is not working, the modal is not displayed.
Is there any alternative way to create modals in Vue

Comment: That's strange, actually I've tested your code on my end, the modal displayed as expected with my way. So please log the `show()` method and make sure it was executed. As for the alternative, i'd recommend a pretty good UI framework [ElementUI](http://element.eleme.io/#/en-US) for you, modal dialog and other UI component are included for Vue applications.

Comment: Hi Kevin,
I tried it again. It worked.
But it is not very user friendly looking.
I will try out the new framework suggested by you and let you know